# Taking 5v and converting it to 3.3v for Raspberry Pi GPIO?

Tags: power, resistors, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi 3b.

For some reason I am having a hard time conceptualizing what I need to do to bring a 5v reading down to 3.3v so I can sense it with my Pi (without damaging it due to the Pi not liking 5v signals).

Scenario:

I have a fan that when it is on there is a 5v potential between the fan + and - terminals when the fan is ON, and of course it is 0v when the fan is off.

There is no way for me to get a current reading due to the fan PCB layout not really having anywhere to put the probe in series to get the amps. So I am just going to say that I would like to know how to reduce the voltage out of curiosity and if it helps protect my Pi that is even better.

I would like to be able to read that 5v into a GPIO pin so I can determine if the fan is ON or OFF.

My code works right now reading the 5v into the GPIO pin. A stated I am just concerned about put 5v on a GPIO pin.

The wiring flow is that I have a ground wire connecting the - (ground) terminal on the Fan to the Pi ground terminal and the + (hot) terminal on the fan plugged into a GPIO pin that is set to READ mode.

What resistors can I place in between the Fan (+) terminal and the GPIO pin to reduce the voltage down to 3.3v or steps I can take to reduce the potential damage to the Pi.

Comment: you need a shifter to shift down 5V to 3.3V. If you provide basic connections diagram u can take more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a resistive voltage divider? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider
If you want to be sure, that the voltage across the lower resistor never exceeds 3 V, you can add a zener diode in parallel with it (anode to ground, cathode to the common node between the resistors). The upper node of the top resistor goes to the fan, the common node to the raspberry and the ground node to - terminal of the fan and ground from raspberry.

Comment: Any chance you could mock up a breadboard example of what I need to place where? There are some really cool breadboard simulators that are web based now. I just cant figure out what to put where.

Comment: Breadboard simulators are not cool; they are for beginners and amateurs and hobbyists (at the lowest grade) and, to request that anyone answering your question uses one to help you is kind of missing the point.

Comment: @Andy AKA: thanks for this comment. Agree!

Comment: So JohnKubik, please feel free to draw, what you understood so far and mark the connections you don't know what to do with. Then we'll take it from there.

Comment: I just played around with a 10k and a 20k resistor until the reading was 3.3v.

Comment: @ANDY AKA .... wow. great way to really encourage knowledge sharing. I am reporting your comment.

Comment: Ok, you’re still at school yes?

Answer (score 1):

Consider just using a dedicated level shifter if you don't want to have to worry about impedances and sinking/sourcing current.  Something such as:
https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/09/using-a-level-shifter-with-the-raspberry-pi-gpio/